# Was this subject complement diagrammed correctly?

Tags: compound-adjectives, present-participles, complements, diagramming, predicate-nominative

The sentence is the following. I'm focusing on the part in **bold**:

> Feeding the goats is messy and **time consuming**.

It's in this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00I1P8OPY).

The author provides the following diagram:
[image]

And I think it should look like this, a present participle (curved line) modifying the noun *time*, both forming a compound adjective:
[image]

Comment: 'Time-consuming' is classed as a single lexeme, a compound adjective, by CD, M-W, Collins, Macmillan, Longman, OLD, AHD .... I'd say it persists as such in predicative usage, but the hyphen is sometimes dropped [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/time-consuming)]. How do you usually diagram open compounds?

Answer (score 1):

I love this question.  It points out an interesting aspect of how the present participle forms phrases versus how the present progressive tense operates--and the difference in meaning.

But, first to answer your question.  Simplifying the example to, "Feeding goats is time consuming," makes clear that "is" acts as a linking verb.  So, "time consuming" must be a subject complement, which means that it must be in the nature of an adjective or a noun.  "Time consuming" definitely is not a noun.  To prove it, try to use it as the subject of a simple sentence.  It won't make sense.  It must be an adjective.  Since it must be an adjective, its head should be an adjective.  Between "time" and "consuming", "consuming" is a present participle which acts like an adjective, and "time" is not an adjective.  So, "consuming" must be at the head, and "time" must be complementing it or modifying it.  Since, "time" is a noun, it doesn't really modify other words, so it cannot be a modifier.  It must be acting as a complement.  In this case, it is a complement (or direct object) of the present participle, "consuming."

The cool things, here, is that "time" can go before or after "consuming."  "Feeding goats is time consuming," and "Feeding goats is consuming time," both work.  The former is constructed with the present participle, and suggests that the act of feeding goats takes a lot of time.  The latter uses the present progressive, "is consuming," and suggests that a specific and currently happening event of a feeding goats is using time.

I would argue that the particular construct of your example is almost idiomatic in nature. Normally, "time" as a complement of the present participle would follow the present participle.  Here, "time" precedes the present participle because, otherwise, the sentence would have an entirely different meaning.  Inserting "time" between "is" and "consuming" prevents inadvertent formation of the present progressive verb.  But, it also makes for some confusing syntax for purposes of diagramming.

Comment: Hi Matthew! Thank you for your answer. Yes, both structures seem to have the same sense, but shouldn't we take into account parallel structures—*is making a mess* (transitive verb + object)/(is) *consuming time* (transitive verb + object) or *messy *(adjective)/*time consuming*(adjective)? And, I agree, if we consider *time consuming* as a subject complement then it makes sense that it is a present participle and its object.

Comment: As in [here](https://i.postimg.cc/fyVcycJv/Solution.jpg).

Comment: Sorry to be slow in responding.  I see your point about parallelism, but there are many instances in which that sort of structure is not parallel.  E.g., "The ocean waves are beautiful and a danger."  --  As I take a fresh look at your question and the author's diagram, I wonder, could "consuming" be a gerund, with "time" forming a phrase with it like two nouns might form a phrase?  Such as, "room key."  In other words, can noun-gerund interact in the same way that noun-noun can interact?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the author is right. "Time" is just an object in the adjective phrase "time consuming", which is built on the model "verb and object"; you can say "feeding is consuming time".
It wouldn't be correct to say "feeding is consuming" as something would be felt to be missing (time, energy, supplies, …), yet it would make some sense; however, "feeding is time" can't make any sense except in a very elliptical manner as  in "Time is money" (of course, speaking literally, "time" is not "money").
According to this understanding "time" is accessory in the syntax; therefore, it is made to depend on the branch rather than constituting it.

Comment: You touched an interesting point: "feeding is time" is indeed nonsensical. I think I see what you mean. I had thought about it as you mentioned (in reverse): feeding is consuming something, and that is time, but couldn't it be that they are working as a compound adjective, and the phrase is a predicate adjective, what makes sense? And, if it is an object of a verbal, then shouldn't it be diagrammed as such (└─)?

Comment: I mean, like [this](https://i.postimg.cc/fyVcycJv/Solution.jpg).

Comment: @mjfneto The two ideas are not incompatible: the adjective is on the level of the clause a predicate adjective and on the level of morphology a compound adjectival construction of the type "verb object"; the type of diagramming you are studying is relatively new and I do not know it but it is evident that it goes beyond the usual scope of diagramming, which is syntax; although morphology is a part of grammar, it has not been  taken into account in traditional diagramming; so, you are concerned with two levels, the syntactical and the morphological; (1/2)

Comment: @mjfneto  necessarily, the morphological must be confined to the particular constituent that is being analysed morphologically. That is why placing  "time" after "consuming", which gives to those elements a syntactical nature that they do not have, is wrong in my opinion. By the same token the beginning of your diagram does not reflect the reality of two levels: "goats" cannot be found on the level of a morphological component of "feeding". But, as I told you, I am not familiar with this new type of diagram. (2/2)

Comment: You brought up nteresting points, @LPH. Would you have a reference on sentence diagramming which goes over the different approaches that have been developed?

Comment: @mjfneto Sentence diagramming is not treated in depth by any grammar I know; most often what you get on diagramming, if anything, is a brief introduction and no systematic use of diagrams; in an 1800 page grammar I found hardly more than the three following diagrams, ( I let you have them so that you might start a study of your own in case you find no satisfactory reference): [D1](https://postimg.cc/delete/jBWrVVZW/1e544894), [D2](https://postimg.cc/delete/fPCqv2f1/4240dd95), [D3](https://postimg.cc/delete/kz6jqnPd/19e40002).

Comment: I appreciate it, @LPH.

Comment: Shall we go a few steps back? If ‘time’ is just a verbal complement, an object, I still don't understand why it was diagrammed as a modifier. Again, verbal complements should be diagrammed like [this](https://i.postimg.cc/fyVcycJv/Solution.jpg), right?

Comment: @mjfneto The way you draw it now is similar to "feeding the goats": there is a vertical bar between "feeding" and "goat". "Goat" is the object of "feeding" and  the  function (object) is a _syntactical_ one in this context; however, using the same scheme for "time consuming" is wrong, it misrepresent the constituents because, if there is again a relation of verb(consume) to an object (time), it is not at all syntactical but _morphological_, that is, it is found on the level of the form  ("morpho" is "form" in Greek) of the constituent "time- consuming" which is one single word (an adjective).

Comment: @mjfneto https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/time-consuming?q=time-consuming

Comment: I think I see what you mean. So, in this case, the adjective was used without an hyphen (time consuming), one [explanation](https://www.espressoenglish.net/compound-adjectives-in-english/) is that the compound loses the hyphen when it comes after the noun it modifies (feeding the goats). So it isn't a single word anymore, morphologically, right? I guess that's why the author put ‘time’ as a modifier. But what kind of modifier is that? ‘Time’ is a noun, right? Is it an attributive noun? But ‘consuming’ is functioning as an adjective. Is it an attributive noun modifying an adjective?

Comment: @mjfneto There is no scheme of correspondence; most often  you have only one (thought-provoking, preparing diner), sometimes you have the two of them (time-saving, saving time). So, saying that the compound  looses the hyphen is not relevant; either  a hyphen is used to form a word, either you use the words without a hyphen and in reverse order to construct a clause. You have compounds such as "goat feeding station" but there is no hyphen and "goat-feeding" is not an adjective; this combination does not exist as an adjective.  (1/2)

Comment: @mjfneto No, no attributive noun: only one relation and that is "object". "Consuming" is not functioning as an adjective, "time-consuming", only,  is an adjective. (2/2)

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble trying to understand this. How are ‘time-consuming’ and ‘time consuming’ different? When I look at Collins COBUILD Advance Lerner's English Dictionary, it says “time-consuming also time consuming ADJ”, so they differ only morphologically not sintatically? You are saying that when there's no hyphen, it's a clause?

Comment: @mjfneto Comments are not allowed anymore. If you want to go on with this discussion, please, open a room for this subject, and I'll join you there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120194/discussion-between-mjfneto-and-lph).

Comment: @mjfneto My FSE account has been suspended today for 90 days  (they forbid me to use it) and they forbid me to participate in discussions on all chats, which means that I wont be able to continue. Sorry for that.

Comment: Reed–Kellogg diagramming systems lack many features that make them unsuitable to serious grammar study. One such is the angle line for modification. Another is the absence of internal structure -- _pony ride_ and _snake bite_ would show up the same, but they're opposites: one rides a pony (active object) or is bitten by the snake (passive agent). No way to show that. Also, any sentence with more than two clauses is hopeless, and that's 99% of English sentences. But it's fine for first and second grades.